# How to submit a single form in a page?

Tags: javascript, post, submit

I have two forms on my page.

I want to submit one form only.

But when I use the submit button it submits all the forms in that page.

how can I submit a single form with JavaScript?

my code like,

```
<form name="f1" method='post' action=''>
  <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

<form name="f2" method='post' action=''>
  <input type='text' name='text2'>
  <input type='button' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen and doesn't happen with the posted code. Make sure the forms are independant and not nested.

Comment: I found this page because I was having a similar issue. The problem seems to arise when you have multiple forms in 1 table. The simple solution is to declare which forms your inputs relate to i.e. <form id=f1 ...> <input form=f1 ... >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the form ID to a Javascript "submitter" function and use it to submit:

```
<form name="f1" id="f1" method='post' action=''>
  <a href="javascript: submitform("f1")">submit</a>
</form>

<form name="f2" id="f2" method='post' action=''>
  <input type='text' name='text2'>
  <a href="javascript: submitform("f2")">submit</a>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform(frmId)
{
  myFrm = document.getElementById(frmId);
  myFrm.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the input type submit to button and make a click event for every button to submit respective form,

```
<input type="button" onClick="submit_form1()" value="submit form1">

<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_form1()
{   alert("submit me");
f1.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: This solution is not generic, meaning, if he'll have 100 forms in the page he'll need 100 JS functions...

Comment: Completely unnecessary, a submit button in one form should not submit a different form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--
(1) Property 'name' has no meaning in 'form' tag
(2) Set the desired URL in 'action'
(3) Set ID for the forms to call from JS
(4) Use JavaScript to call the '.submit()' method
-->

<form method="POST" action='your-page-url' id="form1">
  <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>

<form method="POST" action='your-page-url' id="form2">
  <input type='text' name='text2'/>
  <input type='button' value='submit'/>
</form>

<button onclick="submit_form('form1');">Submit form 1</button>
<button onclick="submit_form('form2');">Submit form 2</button>

<script>
function submit_form(Form_Id) {
  var Form = document.getElementById(Form_Id);
  Form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms['f1'].submit();` first form will get submitted ,but here you does not need a js submission when you press submit the form corresponding to the that submit button will only be submitted .this will be clear if u print the post value at server side.in your second form u need a submit  button not a simple button .submit button has got a default propery of auto submit a form ,where as a type button we need to specify the action.

```
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
```